# Flutter rating bar package selected and unselected containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

What I have:

[image: have]

What I want:

[image: want]

I am using [`flutter_rating_bar`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar) package and I want it to show the unselected containers as is instead of the default grey color and only want to change the color for the selected container.

As shown in the above pictures, instead of the grey boxes I want to display the remaining unselected containers preceding the selected ones as shown in the second picture.

Code:

```dart
RatingBar.builder(
  initialRating: initialRatings,
  itemCount: 5,
  itemSize: 50,
  itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: containerWidth * 0.0077),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return Container(
          width: ratingContainerWidth,
          height: ratingContainerHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: knowledgeRating == 1
                ? const Color.fromRGBO(109, 44, 237, 1)
                : const Color.fromRGBO(226, 243, 255, 1),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(
            '1',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: knowledgeRating == 1
                  ? const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              fontSize: 16,
              letterSpacing: 0.20000000298023224,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 1:
        return Container(
          width: ratingContainerWidth,
          height: ratingContainerHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: knowledgeRating == 2
                ? const Color.fromRGBO(109, 44, 237, 1)
                : const Color.fromRGBO(226, 243, 255, 1),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(
            '2',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: knowledgeRating == 2
                  ? const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              fontSize: 16,
              letterSpacing: 0.20000000298023224,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 2:
        return Container(
          width: ratingContainerWidth,
          height: ratingContainerHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: knowledgeRating == 3
                ? const Color.fromRGBO(109, 44, 237, 1)
                : const Color.fromRGBO(226, 243, 255, 1),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(
            '3',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: knowledgeRating == 3
                  ? const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              fontSize: 16,
              letterSpacing: 0.20000000298023224,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 3:
        return Container(
          width: ratingContainerWidth,
          height: ratingContainerHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: knowledgeRating == 4
                ? const Color.fromRGBO(109, 44, 237, 1)
                : const Color.fromRGBO(226, 243, 255, 1),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(
            '4',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: knowledgeRating == 4
                  ? const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              fontSize: 16,
              letterSpacing: 0.20000000298023224,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 4:
        return Container(
          width: ratingContainerWidth,
          height: ratingContainerHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: knowledgeRating == 5
                ? const Color.fromRGBO(109, 44, 237, 1)
                : const Color.fromRGBO(226, 243, 255, 1),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
          child: Text(
            '5',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: knowledgeRating == 5
                  ? const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              fontSize: 16,
              letterSpacing: 0.20000000298023224,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  },
  onRatingUpdate: (rating) => setState(() {
    knowledgeRating = rating;
  }),
),
```

Comment: please provide any snippet code

Comment: hi, I have updated it in the question.

Comment: I think all you missed is break; statement after you cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do with [`flutter_rating_bar`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar). Checking the sources, if the `itemBuilder` is being used [there is a color filter applied to the child](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_rating_bar/blob/e58be029c1959fb7ea760da65a2689df6244e8ed/lib/src/rating_bar.dart#L489-L497) that blends the `unratedColor` with the child widget. This `unratedColor` is the source and it always wins because of the filter that is set to [`BlendMode.srcIn`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode.html).

This filter is not applied only if the `itemBuilder` is null. But the only way to make it null is to [use the default constructor](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_rating_bar/blob/e58be029c1959fb7ea760da65a2689df6244e8ed/lib/src/rating_bar.dart#L54-L55) and set the `ratingWidget` that repeats the same for all ratings.

Fortunately, the source code is available and it's just a matter of forking it, [removing the filter](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_rating_bar/blob/e58be029c1959fb7ea760da65a2689df6244e8ed/lib/src/rating_bar.dart#L489-L496) and pointing the fork in `pubspec.yaml` to get the desired result like below:

[image]

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
# ...
dependencies:
  flutter_rating_bar:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/your_git_repo/flutter_rating_bar.git
      ref: master
```

The changed widget without the color filter.

```dart
class _NoRatingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  _NoRatingWidget({
    required this.size,
    required this.child,
    required this.enableMask,
    required this.unratedColor,
  });

  final double size;
  final Widget child;
  final bool enableMask;
  final Color unratedColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: size,
      width: size,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```